# Create XRM EntityMetadata

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, xrm

I'm developing an XRM plugin for Microsoft Dynamics CRM.  I'd like to be able, using only XRM assembly references, and no CRM kernel code, to instantiate an object of type EntityMetadata.  I've only been able to get as far as declaring an object of type EntityMetadata:

```
EntityMetadata entityMetadata;
```

Using CRM kernel code, an object of type EntityMetadata can be instantiated like this:

```
EntityMetadata entityMetadata = MetadataCache.GetInstance(((PipelineExecutionContext)context).PlatformContext)
                                    .GetEntity(entityName, NameMappingType.Logical);
```

The constraints of my project dictate that I only use XRM code, and I'm not allowed to reference any of the more familiar Microsoft.Crm.* assemblies.

Comment: this is a real project or just a poc for yourself?

Comment: The CRM assemblies are already available on the server, so the assembly you register on the server doesn't need to merge them in...are you sure you can't reference them just to write your code? Seems like a very odd constraint, can you tell us more about it?

Answer (score 0):

One option: Just use a RetrieveEntityRequest message. It's already in the Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk namespace.

Is this what you mean?

More info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrieveentityrequest.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses.  This is a proof of concept.  We were asked to remove code from the CRM kernel, and rely primarily on XRM assemblies.  Here is the approach we came up with for EntityMetadata:

```
DynamicMetadataCache metadata = MetadataCache.GetInstance(((PipelineExecutionContext)context).PlatformContext);
EntityMetadata entityMetadata = metadata.GetEntity(entity.LogicalName, NameMappingType.Logical);
```